# Accessing 3d array in R

Tags: r, rstudio

Was working with a 3 dimensional dataset HairEyeColor. Essentially, it looks like this:

[image: data]

I want to access the entire array where Sex is Male. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extract at the 3rd dimension either with the name

```
HairEyeColor[,, "Male"]
#  Eye
#Hair    Brown Blue Hazel Green
#  Black    32   11    10     3
#  Brown    53   50    25    15
#  Red      10   10     7     7
#  Blond     3   30     5     8
```

or the index

```
HairEyeColor[,, 1]
```